# Getting JSON from CURL in C#

Tags: c#, json, curl, zendesk

I'm trying to get a JSON string via CURL:

```
curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_fields/{id}.json \
-v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

I can't get my head around how to convert this into a C# command, but I have been trying to use the WebClient and WebRequst class, but without any luck.

First i tried to access the URL via the WebClient:

```
var tags = api.Tickets.GetTicketFieldById(123456789);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "abc123", "https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2");
string json = client.DownloadString(tags.TicketField.Url);
```

But it throws an exception of 401 un-authorized.

I tried the same approach with the WebRequest/WebResponse, but same error came. I saw Zendesk was providing a CURL string to access the data, but I'm not sure on how to convert the CURL string into a C# command.

Can anybody help me access the returning JSON string?

Thanks in advance, Jesper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string json;
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("{email_address}", "{password}");
    json = client.DownloadString(
        "https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/ticket_fields/{id}.json");
}
// use json...
```

Obviously you'll need to replace the values. I'm assuming that isn't the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm replacing the values. But I guess i got the NetworkCredentials wrong, by entering the wrong uri. Thanks :)